# How to scrape posts from a subreddit from a specific year?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I'm trying to retrieve all the posts from a subreddit that were created in 2020.

Below is the code I wrote to try to solve this

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime

subreddit = reddit_read_only.subreddit("SuicideWatch")

# Scraping the top posts of all time
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter = "all")
 
posts_dict = {"Title": [], "Post Text": [],
              "ID": [], "Score": [], "Upvote Ratio": [],
              "Total Comments": [],"Created On":[], "Post URL": [],
              "Original Content": []
              }

start_date = '01-01-20 00:00:00'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()

for post in posts:
    # Date of each posts' creation
    date = post.created_utc
    if date > start_date:
        # Title of each post
        posts_dict["Title"].append(post.title)
     
        # Text inside a post
        posts_dict["Post Text"].append(post.selftext)
     
        # Unique ID of each post
        posts_dict["ID"].append(post.id)
     
        # The score of a post
        posts_dict["Score"].append(post.score)
        
        # Upvote Ratio of a post
        posts_dict["Upvote Ratio"].append(post.upvote_ratio)
     
        # Total number of comments inside the post
        posts_dict["Total Comments"].append(post.num_comments)
         
        # Date the post was Created
        posts_dict["Created On"].append(post.created_utc)
        
        # URL of each post
        posts_dict["Post URL"].append(post.url)
        
        # Flair of each post
        posts_dict["Original Content"].append(post.is_original_content)
        
# Saving the data in a pandas dataframe
all_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts_dict)
all_posts
```

I know that the limit is 100, however, my code is only returning 79 posts. I need a few hundred posts to build a proper dataset for a project.

I also noticed that the "Created On" column is a float. I used the following code to try to get it as a date. Is this correct?

```
all_posts["Created On"] = pd.to_datetime(all_posts["Created On"] * 1000000000).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

I modified one line to set the limit as None so it returned over the default limit of 100 posts.

```
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter = "all", limit = None)
```

This resulted in scraping 764 posts instead of just 79.

Afterwards I altered the "Created On" column into a date using the following:

```
all_posts['Created On'] = pd.to_datetime(all_posts['Created On'],  unit='s')
```

Then I was able to filter for posts created in 2020-2021.

Full Code Below:

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime

subreddit = reddit_read_only.subreddit("SuicideWatch")

# Scraping the top posts of all time
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter = "all", limit = None)
 
posts_dict = {"Title": [], "Post Text": [],
              "ID": [], "Score": [], "Upvote Ratio": [],
              "Total Comments": [],"Created On":[], "Post URL": [],
              "Original Content": []
              }

start_date = '01-01-20 00:00:00'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()

for post in posts:
    # Date of each posts' creation
    date = post.created_utc
    if date > start_date:
        # Title of each post
        posts_dict["Title"].append(post.title)
     
        # Text inside a post
        posts_dict["Post Text"].append(post.selftext)
     
        # Unique ID of each post
        posts_dict["ID"].append(post.id)
     
        # The score of a post
        posts_dict["Score"].append(post.score)
        
        # Upvote Ratio of a post
        posts_dict["Upvote Ratio"].append(post.upvote_ratio)
     
        # Total number of comments inside the post
        posts_dict["Total Comments"].append(post.num_comments)
         
        # Date the post was Created
        posts_dict["Created On"].append(post.created_utc)
        
        # URL of each post
        posts_dict["Post URL"].append(post.url)
        
        # Flair of each post
        posts_dict["Original Content"].append(post.is_original_content)
        
# Saving the data in a pandas dataframe
all_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts_dict)
all_posts['Created On'] = pd.to_datetime(all_posts['Created On'],  unit='s')
all_posts
```